# ipconfig release/renew for Wi-Fi doesn't work

Tags: windows-10, ipconfig

```
ipconfig /renew Wi-Fi
ipconfig /release Wi-Fi
```

Either of those commands don't work for the Wi-Fi adapter yet they work fine for the Ethernet adapters or any of the other adapters. Like the adapters for VPN or VirtualBox, or I have some wireless connections named Local Area Connection *x (x is a number). It works even for them if I use Local* and it only releases/renews only those adapters only.

When I try Wi-Fi, Wi* or *Fi it doesn't work for it, instead it works as if I didn't supply it an adapter name at all. And executes those commands on all nics.

I should add, if I use a name that isn't available in the list it says this instead "The operation failed as no adapter is in the state permissible for
this operation." Just wondering why it doesn't work specifically for the Wi-Fi adapter.

Comment: AFAIK, the only reason it wouldn't work is if the WiFi adapter is configured with a static IP, as `release`/`renew` only applies to DHCP

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include the output of of `ipconfig /all`

Comment: @JW0914 I see, that makes sense. I am on a mobile hotspot. It says DHCP is enabled yet in the IPv4/Ipv6 addresses it says (Preffered) at the end. I thought it would show that only in case a static IP was assigned. Yet I have not done so. Neither from the desktop nor from the hotspot on my phone.